# How do I send a get request with path variables and query parameters using RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, get, resttemplate

I'm trying to send the following request but I'm getting a message that I have an "ambiguous URI path enconding".

Here's the Get request:

```
ResponseEntity<CarDetail> carDetails = restTemplate.exchange(
                                                    builder.toUriString(),
                                                    HttpMethod.GET,
                                                    requestEntity,
                                                    CarDetail.class,
                                                    carId, ownerId);
```

builder is like this:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
                .queryParam("from", "2019-04-12T10:15:51.000Z")
                .queryParam("to", "2019-04-14T10:15:51.000Z");
```

and url is like this:

```
http://cars.com/car/{carId}/owner/{ownerId}/period
```

I've been trying to find where's the problem but couldn't figure out, any help would be appreciated.

---

**Update**:
the `builder.toUriString()` is returning this:

```
http://cars.com/car/%7BcarId%7D/owner/%7BownerId%7D/period?from=2019-04-12T10:15:51.000Z&to=2019-04-14T10:15:51.000Z
```

I think that the problem is with the `%7B` thing. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem using `builder.buildAndExpand(carVariable).toUri()`

The solution looks like this:

```
ResponseEntity<CarDetail> carDetails = restTemplate.exchange(
       builder.buildAndExpand(carVariable).toUri(),
       HttpMethod.GET,
       requestEntity,
       CarDetail.class);
```

Comment: Saved my life, thanks! Another possibility is to pass a Map to the buildAndExpand().